# Sequence is incremented even if no INSERT occurs

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

I've a table with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE web.cabinet_account_section (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    section_id text NULL,
    account_id int4 NULL,
    cabinet_param_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cabinet_account_section_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT cabinet_account_section_section_id_account_id_key UNIQUE (section_id),
    CONSTRAINT cabinet_account_section_account_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES web.cabinet_account(id),
    CONSTRAINT cabinet_account_section_cabinet_param_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (cabinet_param_id) REFERENCES web.cabinet_param(id)
);
```

The table is updated every day. Until recently, the table was updated as follows: if the `UNIQUE section_id` already exists (i.e., a regular SELECT EXISTS is executed), then nothing needs to be added. About 10,000 entries come to the entrance every day.

I decided to replace this logic with simple UPSERT:

```
INSERT INTO web.cabinet_account_section (section_id, account_id, cabinet_param_id)
VALUES ('${view.id}', '${account.id}', 2)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

But then there was a small problem with the serial field. With every `INSERT INTO` query, the **id serial is automatically incremented, even if no record has been inserted**. Those the last id in the column was conditionally = 1800. Yesterday several new records appeared in the table with the following id: 2300, 2560, 8120, 9982. Today the id has already exceeded 20,000. Those it tries to INSERT, increments the counter, does not insert, but does not roll back the counter.

I think that after a couple of months it will eventually hit the serial range limit even without adding new rows.

Sequence script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE web.cabinet_account_id_seq
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    START 1
    CACHE 1
    NO CYCLE;
```

Is it possible to somehow fix this case? It's one thing when you just delete a record from the table and some kind of ID just disappears. But here sequence grows exponentially even without inserting any rows. Or should i return to the old version with a check to see if such a section_id already exists?

Comment: Yes, this is how it works, check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: Sequence generated values are expected to have gaps. There is nothing to worry about. The **only** job for such a value is to be unique. It is totally irrelevant whether that value is 1,42,9982 or 932887 or -35428. You have nothing to worry